# jConfirm and onbeforeunload

Tags: jquery, jconfirm

I have a basic function to alert the user upon refresh, browser back button (except the submit button) or when a link is clicked they will lose form data from a form wizard.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var okToSubmit = false;
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    document.getElementById('Register').onclick = function() { okToSubmit = true; };
    if(!okToSubmit) return "Using the browsers back button will cause you to lose all form data. Please use the Next and Back buttons on the form"; 
};
</script>
```

Im using jAlert plug in for alerts and would like to use jConfirm for the function above. When I add jConfirm after "return" it works...for a second. it pops the warning and then the page refreshes and the dialog box goes away. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you still need to `return false;`, otherwise the unload action still occurs. I'm not familiar with the plugin, but try something like:

```
// your code
if(!okToSubmit) 
{ 
    alert( "Using the browsers back button will cause you to lose all form data. Please use the Next and Back buttons on the form" );
    return false;
}
// the rest of your code
```

Comment: If the plugin expects a return of either `true` or `whatever your response is`, then disregard this answer.

Comment: thx ill give it a shot, will the "alert" work the same as a confirm dialogue?

Comment: nope. Alert just alerts. Confirm gives the option. So you can switch it to `var whatTheySaid = confirm( "are you srsly ready yo?" )` and then do stuff based on the return (true or false).

Comment: That solved the problem of the dialog box disappearing, although it now pops the jConfirm message as well as the standard browser message on top of it

Comment: I'm not sure how that plugin works. Maybe there's a way to send it the info to confirm? Or... maybe don't use the plugin?